# ZAP Jenkins configuration for windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, zap

I am a beginner in Jenkins and I am trying to use Jenkins with the ZAP plugin.

I managed to follow the step-by-step guideline provided by Jenkins but I have some questions regarding what actually ZAP for Jenkins can manage.

If I just use ZAP without Jenkins I can write the path of the server I would like to test, and the process will start.

However,ZAP for Jenkins requires the source code of the website. Is there an option to just import the url of the site I would like to test and then proceed?

It might be a silly question but It really bothers me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to ask on the ZAP Jenkins group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21forum/zaproxy-jenkins. I know that the project lead doesnt monitor stackoverflow.